# How to select or highlight all items in a QTreeWidget?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qtreewidget, qtreewidgetitem

I'm trying to build a context menu that user can right-click on a QTreeWidget and select all items.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `QTreeView.selectAll()` but only after setting the selection mode to something that allows multiple selection (using `QAbstractItemView.setSelectionMode()`).

Example (in PyQt4 use QtGui instead of QtWidgets):

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

widget = QtWidgets.QTreeWidget()
widget.addTopLevelItems([QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(['dog']), QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(['car'])])
widget.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.ContiguousSelection)
widget.selectAll()

widget.show()

app.exec_()
```

and it looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way that will recursively go through each item and its children and select them all.  It takes advantage of the [`invisibleRootItem`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtreewidget.html#invisibleRootItem) at the root of each `QTreeWidget`.  You could also pass any item in the tree to this function and it would select that item and all its children.

```
def select_item(item)
    item.setSelected(True)
    for i in range(item.childCount()):
        child = item.child(i)
        select_item(child)

item = tree.invisibleRootItem()
select_item(item)
```